# How to use Eigen::Matrix by reference

Tags: c++11, matrix, eigen

I have a small problem, but i don't know how to solve it.

Let's start:
I need to work on a big Eigen Matrix using multithreads.
Each thread need to access to the matrix. The dimension is specified during the program execution, so I must declare it inside the main(), and not as global. I tried different solutions without success. I search something like "pass by reference" but i read that this method don't work with Eigen Matrix.
Here there is a small example. Can someone tell me how can I solve this problem? The program need to be fast, so something like: -save the matrix in a file, and read the file in each thread, work on the matrix, save the matrix in a file, re-read the file from the main- is not the best way, I think... ;) Does someone know a better solution?
Thanks at all!

```
void calc() {
    // work on the Matrix
}

int main() {
    Eigen::Matrix<bool, a, b> Mat;
    // Start some thread(calc);
    cout << Mat;
}
```

Comment: just pass `Mat` to `calc` by reference, that is using the type `Matrix<bool, a, b>&`. You can also declare it globally and call `Mat.resize(rows,cols);` but that's ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Si !** Eigen matrix **can** be passed as a reference.

Here's a working example :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

void calc(Eigen::MatrixXf& mat) {
    mat = Eigen::MatrixXf::Constant(mat.rows(), mat.cols(), 1.0);
}

int main() {
    Eigen::MatrixXf Mat;
    Mat = Eigen::Matrix4f::Identity();
    std::cout << Mat << std::endl;
    calc(Mat);
    std::cout << Mat << std::endl;
}
```

- Output :

  ```
  1 0 0 0    
  0 1 0 0    
  0 0 1 0    
  0 0 0 1

  1 1 1 1
  1 1 1 1
  1 1 1 1
  1 1 1 1
  ```

Comment: Thanks!!! it work with a small change:
this is the working-code with thread (compiled with -lpthread); the problem was that i don't use std::ref(Mat) in thread initialization!

#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <thread>

void calc(Eigen::MatrixXf& mat) {
    mat = Eigen::MatrixXf::Constant(mat.rows(), mat.cols(), 1.0);
}

int main() {
    Eigen::MatrixXf Mat;
    Mat = Eigen::Matrix4f::Identity();
    std::cout << Mat << std::endl;
    std::thread a(calc, std::ref(Mat));
    //calc(Mat);
    std::cout << Mat << std::endl;
}

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify the matrix and the matrix could come from either `Eigen::MatrixXd` or [`Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd>`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMapClass.html), then you can only use `Eigen::Ref<Eigen::MatrixXd>`. This is common if you want to refactor some legacy projects by mapping a `std::vector` to an `Eigen::VectorXd` or `Eigen::MatrixXd` without making copies.

```cpp
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// // ERROR:
// // candidate function not viable: no known conversion from
// // 'Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd>' (aka 'Map<Matrix<double, Dynamic,
// // Dynamic>>') to 'Eigen::MatrixXd &' (aka 'Matrix<double, Dynamic, Dynamic>
// // &') for 1st argument
// void calc(Eigen::MatrixXd &eigen_mat) { eigen_mat *= 2.0; }

// OK
void calc(Eigen::Ref<Eigen::MatrixXd> eigen_mat) { eigen_mat *= 2.0; }

int main() {
  std::vector<double> vec(9, 1.0);
  { // OK for both `Eigen::MatrixXd &` and `Eigen::Ref<Eigen::MatrixXd>`
    Eigen::MatrixXd eigen_mat = Eigen::MatrixXd::Constant(3, 3, 1.0);
    calc(eigen_mat);
    std::cout << "MatrixXd:\n" << eigen_mat << std::endl;
  }
  { // OK only for `Eigen::Ref<Eigen::MatrixXd>`
    Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd> eigen_mat(vec.data(), 3, 3);
    calc(eigen_mat);
    std::cout << "Map<MatrixXd>:\n" << eigen_mat << std::endl;
  }
}
```